# Pandas loc returning NaN values for rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which I import using pd.read_csv(). There are 59 columns in the raw data, I only need 13 columns. loc returns NaN values for the row data. See code below:

```
file = 'es.txt'

data = pd.read_csv(file)
print(data.head())
       Date         Time   Open   High    Low   Last   Volume   # of Trades  \
0  2018/3/7   16:15:00.0  61.25  61.26  61.23  61.24       22            18   
1  2018/3/7   16:20:00.0  61.23  61.24  61.14  61.17       58            42   
2  2018/3/7   16:25:00.0  61.17  61.20  61.17  61.19       68            63   
3  2018/3/7   16:30:00.0  61.20  61.20  61.19  61.20       12             8   
4  2018/3/7   16:35:00.0  61.20  61.24  61.20  61.24       11            11   

    OHLC Avg   HLC Avg    ...      200Line   -100Line   -200Line   Main Slope  \
0      61.24     61.24    ...        200.0     -100.0     -200.0    -nan(ind)   
1      61.19     61.18    ...        200.0     -100.0     -200.0    -nan(ind)   
2      61.18     61.19    ...        200.0     -100.0     -200.0      253.379   
3      61.20     61.20    ...        200.0     -100.0     -200.0      146.660   
4      61.22     61.23    ...        200.0     -100.0     -200.0      229.741   

    Turbo Slope      Diff   150Line   -150Line   50Line   -50Line  
0     -nan(ind)       nan     150.0     -150.0     50.0     -50.0  
1     -nan(ind)   266.684     150.0     -150.0     50.0     -50.0  
2       108.591   121.896     150.0     -150.0     50.0     -50.0  
3        62.854    38.090     150.0     -150.0     50.0     -50.0  
4        98.461    93.191     150.0     -150.0     50.0     -50.0  

[5 rows x 59 columns]



# only get the 13 columns I need, and 5 rows
columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Last', 
           'Volume', '# of Trades', 'CCI Main', 'CCI Turbo',
           'MainSlope', 'TurboSlope', 'Diff']
df = data.loc[1:5, columns]
print(df)
       Date  Time  Open  High  Low  Last  Volume  # of Trades  CCI Main  \
1  2018/3/7   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN       NaN   
2  2018/3/7   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN       NaN   
3  2018/3/7   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN       NaN   
4  2018/3/7   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN       NaN   
5  2018/3/7   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN          NaN       NaN   

   CCI Turbo  MainSlope  TurboSlope  Diff  
1        NaN        NaN         NaN   NaN  
2        NaN        NaN         NaN   NaN  
3        NaN        NaN         NaN   NaN  
4        NaN        NaN         NaN   NaN  
5        NaN        NaN         NaN   NaN
```

This is returning NaN values. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you get from `df.columns`? Is there any leading/trailing space in the column names?

Comment: Looks like there's at least some spaces in between 'Turbo Slope' and 'Main Slope' that need to be added. Perhaps you can do `cols = df.columns.tolist()` to look at the specific string column names, and then remove the ones you don't need by index from the cols list, or do `cols.remove('200Line')`.

Comment: if a column specified in `columns` doesn't exist in the data frame, it will return a column full of `NaN`s. so your `columns` list should be a subset of `df.columns`. `Main Slope` & `Turbo Slope` are different from `MainSlope` & `TurboSlope`. That's why they're null. The other columns could return null if the column names have spaces at the start of the names. You could fix that by `df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you all for your help. I have implemented Haleemur Ali's code in my script and it fixes the issue.